# esbuild bundle html css js into a single file

Tags: esbuild

i have a directory named src with 3 files:

- index.html
- index.js
- index.css

this is how my html file looks like what [esbuild recommends](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types/#css-from-js)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i would like to bundle all of them into a single html file, such as

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* the content of index.css */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
       // the content of index.js
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but i failed to do it with esbuild even after digging heavily into [esbuild loaders](https://esbuild.github.io/content-types). would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw no direct way of doing this with esbuild, but this is how I achieved the same goal (simplified for brevity);

```js
// build.mjs

import mustache from "mustache";
import * as esbuild from "esbuild";

const htmlTemplate = `<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* the content of index.css */
      {{{ styling }}}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
       // the content of index.js
       {{{ script }}}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
`;

const scriptInput = `
const x = 1;
window.alert(x);
`;

const stylingInput = `
p {
    color: red;
}
`;

const transformOptions = {
    minify: true
};

const scriptTransformResult = await esbuild.transform(scriptInput, {
  ...transformOptions,
  loader: "js",
});
const script = scriptTransformResult.code;

const stylingTransformResult = await esbuild.transform(stylingInput, {
  ...transformOptions,
  loader: "css",
});
const styling = stylingTransformResult.code;

const model = {
  script,
  styling,
};

const htmlView = mustache.render(htmlTemplate, model);
console.log(htmlView);
```

And the output looks like so;

```
$ node build.mjs
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* the content of index.css */
      p{color:red}

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
       // the content of index.js
       const x=1;window.alert(x);

    </script>
    <p>red</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The dependencies I used were `mustache@4.2.0` and `esbuild@0.19.11`.

You could modify the above to read/write the scripts to and from disk using the `node:fs` module or to an S3 bucket or whatever. I removed that logic from the example above to show the core idea.

You could also swap out `mustache` with whatever is trending nowadays if you want.

Having said that, this approach has some disadvantages like lack of bundling and plugin support. Maybe one could use temporary files and a templating engine if you want these features.

Thanks.

Comment: rather than implementing a bundler, i would like to use one with its advanced features.

Comment: I acknowledge that. But I compromised and accepted the above template approach to get work done and move forward. I just shared my answer because I ran into the same dead end as you when trying to use loaders. If there is a better, easier way in the future, I will refactor my approach and edit or delete my answer, thanks. Maybe this GitHub issue might interest you https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/96#issuecomment-626179774